# What does "dear" mean in this sentence?

Tags: vocabulary

> "Oh, Mom, can I go on the train and see him [Harry Potter], Mom, eh please...."
>   "You've already seen him, Ginny, and the poor boy isn't something you goggle at in a zoo. Is he really, Fred? How do you know?"
>   "Asked him. Saw his scar. It's really there - like lightning."
>   "Poor ***dear*** - no wonder he was alone, I wondered. He was ever so polite when he asked how to get onto the platform."
>   <sub><sup>(Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)</sup></sub>

What does *dear* mean? (It seems an exclamation; yet it is after the adjective *poor*. It's not proper to call it. So it could be pointing "Harry Potter".)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't find any online dictionary definitions exactly matching the intended sense here, but I'll just mention that OED has ***dear*** = Dear one, darling.

It's only loosely connected to the "exclamatory" version in *"Oh dear! What can the matter be?"*

Much more relevant is *"Dear Fred"* as the introduction to a letter. Rowling's usage is certainly common in BrE, particularly from mothers and grandmothers. Essentially, adjectival *dear = cherished, valued, loved* is being used as noun *(**one who is** cherished, valued, loved)*.

Note that in this context, *poor = unfortunate*. *"Poor dear!"* is a common expression indicating sympathy and affection - often for a child (or someone being treated as a child), who is suffering in some way.

Comment: "Dear John letter" is also an idiomatic expression referring to a break-up announcement, in which case the feelings of _cherished, valued,_ and _loved_ have apparently evaporated.

Comment: @J.R.: You're quite right! I'd already changed it from my original *"Dear Sir"* before I posted. I'll change it to a more context-relevant, less "idiomatically-loaded", name!